# Как убрать видимость ободка у внешнего border-radius?

Tags: html, css, css3, border

Заметил такую неприятную особенность у `border-radius`, когда при наложении фона вложенного элемента (в данном случае `li`) на внешний (`ul`) виден неприятный ободок. [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/pvkaLmox/)

```css
ul {
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
li.active {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">текст 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">текст 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">текст 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если просто сделать радиус не 4, а 5, то все отлично :) Ну и разницы вы особо не заметите.

Comment: @Levelleor увеличьте блоки и увидите, что "особо"- заметно!
совет не для перфекционистов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант другой - псевдоэлементы. Но, если у вас глаз настолько алмаз, что различия ширины в `1px` - это слишком, то он не для вас.
Суть - у `li.active` нет `border-radius`, к первому и последнему элементу меню присваиваем дополнительный класс, который обеспечивает их соответствующими псевдоэлементами с абсолютным позиционированием. Сдвиаем их(псевдоэлементы) на `1px`, скрывая все, что нужно скрыть. Профит, вы великолепны.
http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/KzXWQN?editors=1100

```css
/* оформление */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  background: darkgrey;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius:4px;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* объект */

ul {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius:4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}
.active.first-link:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -1px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background: darkorange;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.active.last-link:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -2px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background: darkorange;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
.active {  
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li class="active first-link"><a href="#">текст 1</a>
  <li class="no-active"><a href="#">текст 2</a>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">текст 2</a>
  <li class="no-active"><a href="#">текст 2</a>
  <li class="active last-link"><a href="#">текст 2</a>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заливать цветом не весь `ul`, а все `li` по отдельности. Ожидаемо появятся пробелы нежду пунктами, для избежания просто не закрывайте `li`
http://codepen.io/peecaboo/pen/KzXWQN

```css
div {
  background: darkgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}
  li.active {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
  }
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}
li.no-active {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">текст 1</a>
  <li class="no-active"><a href="#">текст 2</a>
  <li class="no-active"><a href="#">текст 2</a>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: во-первых, не закрывать `li`? вижу, что вы не понимаете природу `inline-block` и как с ним взаимодействовать. во-вторых: мне нужно залить именно весь `ul` т.к. он будет растягиваться на всю ширину экрана, в отличие от `li`

Comment: @Вася <li> автоматически закрывается при обнаружении следующего.

Comment: @Вася, я понимаю природу элементов, не нужно так реагировать. Если бы не понимал - не советовал бы. А насчет растягивания `ul` на всю ширину - важное уточнение, которое нужно было указать в вопросе, в противном случае можно понять задачу неправильно